# Error printing results from a query that is inside a for loop

Tags: php

I need help on this.

I have to write a query 12 times with just a different value so I did this and it worked fine:

```
for ($q=1; $q<=11; $q++) {
   $ingConcepto[$q] = "SELECT
                         tbl_ingresos.cantidadpagada AS cp,
                         tbl_conceingresos.concepto AS concepto, 
                         tbl_ingresos.fechapertenece 
                       FROM 
                         tbl_ingresos 
                       LEFT JOIN 
                         tbl_conceingresos 
                       ON 
                         tbl_ingresos.idtipoingreso = tbl_conceingresos.idingreso 
                       WHERE 
                         MONTH(fechapertenece) = '$q' 
                       AND 
                         YEAR(fechapertenece) = $elcueri1"; 
    $resIC[$q] = mysql_query($ingConcepto[$q],$tewNEW);
    $ingConcepto[$q] = mysql_fetch_array($resIC[$q]);
}
```

The problem comes when I need to print a value it does not display anything:

```
echo $ingConcepto7['cp'];
```

Thanks.

Comment: `$ingConcepto7` doesn't seem to be initialised anywhere? you sure it isn't `$ingConcepto[7]['cp']` ?

Comment: thats exactly what i dont know i put $ingConcepto7 because is 1 of the consecutive numbers of $q but i have already trayed 
$ingConcepto7['cp']
$ingConcepto1['cp']
$ingConcepto['cp'] or even what you just have posted and its not working

Comment: try `$ingConcepto[7]['cp']` as the `7` is an array key. What shows if you `print_r($ingConcepto)` ?

Comment: nop its doesnt print anything

Comment: try print_r ($ingConcepto[7]); show us Output

Comment: nothing it does not display anything, 
the query is correct because if i echo $ingConcepto[$q] it retuns me the 12 querys wich i already have teste directly on the navicat and they bring me results

Comment: Maybe you have an error. Use mysql_error() to check this.